# Warum "von Mensch zu Mensch" anstatt "von Menschen zu Menschen"

Tags: grammatical-case, declension

Das Wort "Mensch" gehört zur n-Deklination. Warum sagt man dann "von Mensch zu Mensch" und nicht "von Menschen zu Menschen"?

Comment: Weil da kein Artikel, Adjektiv oder ähnliches vor dem Substantiv steht. Aber ich weiß nicht, wie das in der Grammatik heißt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Phrase "von Mensch zu Mensch" ist ein Spezialfall der Grundphrase "von Person zu Person", welche einer der wenigen Fälle in der deutschen Sprache ist, wenn kein Artikel, aber eine Dativdeklination benutzt wird. Man sieht das deutlich bei "von mir zu dir". Bei "Mensch" und "Menschen" entsteht die unangenehme Situation, dass man die Dativdeklinationsform "dem Menschen" vom Plural "den Menschen" nicht mehr unterscheiden kann, da der Artikel zur Bildung der Phrase bewusst weggelassen wird, da es sich um ein generelles Konzept und nicht einen bestimmten Menschen handelt. Um also klar zu machen, dass die Singularform "Mensch" und nicht der Plural "Menschen" gemeint ist, wird die Phrase als "von Mensch zu Mensch" gebildet, während "von Menschen zu Menschen" impliziert, dass es sich um Gruppen von mehrere Menschen handeln muss.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis. Ich hoffe, es ist nun klarer.

Comment: Die Antwort ist gut, aber vielleicht nützt sie dir nicht viel. Im Grunde reicht dir wahrscheinlich einfach: "Das ist halt ein Ausdruck, der so ist, wie er ist. Lerne ihn und nutze ihn."